# How to remove the white space between y-axis and first bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a bar chart with x being an array of strings and y being use integers.
There is some white space between the first bar and the y-axis. How do make the first bar starts from the y-axis (0 of the x-axis)?

```
plt.bar(price_df['price_range'], price_df['freq'], width=1, edgecolor='black', align='edge')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('1', labelpad=5)
plt.ylabel('y axis', labelpad=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Try `plt.xlim(left=0)`?

Comment: Yes! That works. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `plt.margins(x=0)` or `plt.margins(x=0.01)` would reduce both the left and right margin.

Comment: plt.margins(x=0) works for me.